# How to get only the next post's link and the URL of the thumbnail?

Tags: php, wordpress

Need link (only) of next and previous post (chronologically speaking). If is first or last post, then need link of last or first post respectively. Also, need the post-thumbnail for respective post.

Desired output:

```
<a href="[link to previous post]" class="previous">
  <div class="hover">
    <div style="background: url(<?php ... ?>) no-repeat center center;"></div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="..." class="next">
.
.
.
</a>
```

What I've tried:

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', ...) but how can I insert all those other items inside of the `a` tags?
```

Thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[looks like previous_post_link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) has a "link" parameter where you can customize the content of the link.

Have you tried something like the following?

```
<?php previous_post_link( '%link', '<div> ... %title ... </div>' ); ?>
```

*Pssht*: `%title` will be replaced with the title of the previous post (default behaviour).

Comment: Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, but with one unwieldy block of code:

```
$date = get_the_time('j F Y'); 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'single-post-thumbnail' );
      previous_post_link( 
        '%link', 
        '<div class="text"><div class="date">'.$date.'</div><h3>%title</h3></div><div class="hover"><div style="background: url('.$image[0].') no-repeat center center;"></div></div>'
      );
```

The variables are for the link and the feature image url.